# Como obter o valor do textbox?

Tags: php, formulário, textbox

Quero obter o valor que vou escrever no meu `textbox`. Tudo na mesma página para depois alterar um campo da tabela pelo valor inserido na `textbox`.

```
<form method="POST" action="#">

    <input type=text required name='txtnewpass' autofocus style='width:150px' value='<?php echo "$txtnewpass"; ?>'>
    <input type=submit name=Alterar value=Alterar>

</form>
```

PHP

```
if ($_POST['txtnewpass']){
 $txtnewpass = $_POST['txtnewpass'];
}

$base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
$requete = "UPDATE 'users' SET 
            password='$txtnewpass'
            WHERE login='$login'";
$resultat = $base_hndl->exec($requete); 
echo "<br><b><center>password change</center></b>";
```

Comment: Qual o problema undefined index? seria bom colocar um isset() no if.

Comment: Sim é esse o erro.

Comment: provavelmente o pau que ta dando é um aviso genérico do PHP, que voce pode resolver alterando as configs do php.ini, dá uma lida ai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949304/turn-off-display-error-php-ini

Comment: Alterei o if para if (isset($_POST['txtnewpass']))

Comment: O codigo funciona, mas da-me sempre o erro de undefined

Answer (score 1):

Mete o código todo dentro do if. Se não receber valores não queres que atualize a base dados.

```php
if ($_POST['txtnewpass']){
    $txtnewpass = $_POST['txtnewpass'];

    $base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
    $requete = "UPDATE 'users' SET 
                password='$txtnewpass'
                WHERE login='$login'";
    $resultat = $base_hndl->exec($requete); 
    echo "<br><b><center>password change</center></b>";
}
```